# GWT Arrays.asList not working on interface types

Tags: gwt

Working on a GWT project (2.7.0), i have experienced a very odd client code behaviour.

The following code throws the error "SEVERE: (ReferenceError) : Ljava_io_Serializable_2_classLit_0_g$ is not definedcom.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (ReferenceError) : Ljava_io_Serializable_2_classLit_0_g$ is not defined".

The error occurs, when calling `Arrays.asList()` with a parameter, that has an interface type.
Is this expected behaviour or a GWT bug?

```
// Working
Integer n1 = 1;
Arrays.asList(n1);
// Not working
Serializable n2 = 1;
Arrays.asList(n2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT 2.7's Super Dev Mode (and from the `_g$` in your class literal field, I think that is what you are using) has been observed having other issues like this, but when compiled the issues go away.

If this is indeed what you are seeing, the issue seems to be fixed in 2.8, not yet released: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit/RzsjqX2gGd4/discussion

This behavior is definitely not expected, but if you can confirm that this works correctly when compiled for production and in GWT 2.8, then we at least know the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the typical use of Arrays.asList would be

```
Object myObj = new Object();
List theList = Arrays.asList(new Object[] {myObj});
```

This works in GWT with any kind of interface/class/enum you throw at it.

EDIT : I've tested this with GWT 2.5.1 :

```
public class Foo implements EntryPoint {    

  public static interface MyInterface {
  }

  public static class MyObject implements MyInterface {
  }

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    MyInterface myObject = new MyObject();
    List<MyInterface> myList = Arrays.asList(myObject);

  }

}
```

Isn't it possible that the problem lies somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, this works because 'Object' is not an interface. I was aware of this workaround, but I'm not looking for a workaround

Comment: @Example:
I tried it and it indeed works.
But it's not working with Serializable.
Obviously the problem occurs only, when the interface is widely used or implemented by GWT.
Not working interfaces are for example: Runnable, HasText, HasCell

Comment: Aha! I've just remember that Serializable in GWT doesn't have a lot of compatibility, try to use IsSerializable if possible. If you want to read more about this, read http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.doc.DeveloperGuide.RemoteProcedureCalls.SerializableTypes.html

Comment: The `Serializable` type does work for RPC just fine, and has since at least GWT 1.5 or so. If the question is specific to interfaces, then IsSerializable is going to have the same problems, since it also is just a marker interface that defines no methods, etc.

Comment: @ColinAlworth Ah, ok. That must be the reason I forgot about it.